# Php unable to determine userid availability with jQuery Validate

Tags: php, jquery

I have a problem with using jQuery validate remote function with php. I try to check the user id with query whether the user id is exist or not. But it alway show user is in used.

Here is my jQuery validate code:

```
userID: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5,
                    remote : {
                        url: "checkUserId.php",
                        type: "post"
                    }
                },
```

Here is my php checking code:

```
<?php
     include "session.php";
     include 'dbConnect.php';

     global $conn;

     $requestedID  = $_POST['userID'];

     $query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE _userID = '$requestedID'";
     $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);

     $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($result);
     if($row_count === false){
         echo 'false';
     }
     else if($row_count >=0){
         echo 'true';
     }
?>
```

Anything I did wrong in my query?

Comment: Have you tried debugging `$_POST` to ensure that the correct value is being passed through by jQuery?

Comment: The column is `_userID` or `userid`? Also passing user provided data directly to the sql opens you to injections.

Comment: @scrowler Yes already debug before

Comment: @chris85 Its okay, ignore the injections first. Please stick to the question please...

Comment: the table column is _userID

Comment: @MarcusTan care to share your findings...?

Comment: @scrowler sorry? what findings?

Comment: If you echo $query and execute it on the DB does it return results?

Comment: how to echo the $query as i using remote

Answer (score 2):

Change your if else condition.

```
if($row_count == 0){
echo 'true';
}else{
echo 'false';
}
```

true = not exist, false = exist

Comment: did you tried to echo $row_count? what's the result?

Comment: how to echo the result as i using remote... it does not show anything on my echo

Comment: yeah right, but you can access directly through the browser your php file(checkUserId.php) to see the result.

Comment: this is what i get  
Notice: Undefined index: userID in C:\xampp\htdocs\TNBCMS(Develop)\checkUserId.php on line 7
false

Comment: it means that you are not getting the value of this $_POST['userID'] . check your form if it has a method post and also echo $_POST['userID'] .

Answer (score 0):

I had successfully solved it with this code. Thanks for all the support.

Here is my updated code:

```
<?php
     include "session.php";
     include 'dbConnect.php';

     global $conn;

     $requestedID  = $_REQUEST['userID'];

     $query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE _userID = '$requestedID'";
     $params = array();
     $options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
     $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query , $params, $options);


    $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($result);
    if($row_count >= 1){
        echo 'false';
    }
    else{
        echo 'true';
    }


?>
```